# sed script to conditionally duplicate digits

Tags: unix, sed

I need to write a `sed` script that will do the following:
if a line contains 3 numbers, then from the 4th number, the number will be written twice.

For example, the output of this input:

```
abc 1 def2 3 ab4
123 zy 
ab1cd2ef3gh4z56
```

will be:

```
abc 1 def2 3 ab44 
123 zy 
ab1cd2ef3gh44z5566
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[0-9]/&&/4g' file
```

An alternative, that might be adapted to suit most other seds is:

```
sed '/\(\([0-9][^0-9]*\)\{3\}\)\([0-9]\)/{s//\1\n\3/;h;s/[0-9]/&&/g;G;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n.*/\2\1/}' file
```

- `/\(\([0-9][^0-9]*\)\{3\}\)\([0-9]\)/` if the line contains 4 or more numbers
- `s//\1\n\3/` mark where the 4th number begins with a newline
- `h` copy the marked line into the hold space (HS)
- `s/[0-9]/&&/g` double all numbers in the pattern space (PS)
- `G` append a newline and the HS to the PS
- `s/.*\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n.*/\2\1/` re-arrange the line using the first part of the original line and the second part of the processed line.

Comment: Nice. I never knew the numerical flag could be combined with `g` in GNU sed. Here's a related note in the manual: "Note: the posix standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the g and number modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the numberth, and then match and replace all matches from the numberth on." http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions (And BSD sed in Mac OS X gives an error.)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely easier with `perl` than `sed`:

```
$ cat /tmp/test
abc 1 def2 3 ab4
123 zy 
ab1cd2ef3gh4z56

$ perl -n < /tmp/test -e '
$count = 0;
while (/([^\d]*)(\d)/gi) {
  print $1, (++$count > 3 ? "$2$2" : $2), $3
}
print "\n";
'
```